# Getting a org link to an mu4e message

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

I have my email setup with mu4e and I have org-mu4e so that when I capture a task, a link to the message is added at the end of it. However, I am wondering if there's a way to generate a link to a message so that I can paste it in an old task in my org file. Right now, my way of solving this is to capture a fake task and then copy the link into my old task and delete the fake task.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The org-mode integration is built-in to mu4e, but it is kept in a separate package that is not enabled by default. You have to run

```
(require 'org-mu4e)
```

After that you can use `org-store-link` in both mu4e headers and message modes. The link is then added to a buffer with `org-insert-link` as always.

More in the [manual](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Org_002dmode-links.html).

Answer (score 1):

Open any Org buffer, type <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> (`org-insert-link`, as suggested by Heikki) and then <kbd>RET</kbd> to select the default link. This will insert the latest copied link. No need to capture anything :-).